# Namespace 3.6 in the application descriptor file should be equal or higher than the minimum version 13.0 required by the Flex SDK

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, air-native-extension

I am new to Flash Builder and setup the 4.7 environment according to these instructions: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html

The end of the tutorial involves "Export Release Build" of ANESampleTest (a Flex project) and I am getting this error:

**"Namespace 3.6 in the application descriptor file should be equal or higher than the minimum version 13.0 required by the Flex SDK"**

I do not have a good understanding of Flash/Flex/Air/etc, but following the tutorial to the letter to install Flash Builder, updating the SDK to 3.6, and the partial 'overlay' steps. How do I resolve this error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The fix:** Change the namespace on the second line of /src/ANESampleTest-app.xml

```
FROM: <application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.6">
TO:   <application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/13.0">
```

**A brief and incomplete background:**
The file /src/ANESampleTest-app.xml is the ‘application descriptor file’. When using the project files downloaded with the tutorial (that contained the 3.6 reference), the builder did not find this compatible with the configuration on my computer (a trial version I installed today - 5/3/2014 - and patched according to the tutorial). I never did figure out how to lookup valid namespaces and am still confused about how all the sdk’s relate to each other. I stumbled upon this solution by creating a fresh new project and found that the namespace specified by the new project wizard was “13.0” on this line of this file.

Comment: I see this is really old, but I'm getting this only it says the namespace 0.0 must be higher than 20.0... but my application xml file DOES have 20.0